# .net c++/cli get the content of a pointer

Tags: c++, .net, pointers, c++-cli

I want to learn the corresponding of the following code in c++/cli

```
People* my_people = new People("name","lname");
People* second_people;
&second_people = &my_people;
```

//

```
People^  my_people = gcnew People("name","lname");
People^ second_people;
// what is this line?
```

Actually I want to assign the content of the my_people to the second_people.
So when I change the content of my_people, the content of the second_people must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your first piece of code doesn't compile and is meaningless. `second_people` doesn't point to any object, so you cannot assign a copy to a non-existing object. Instead you should write

```
People* my_people = new People("name","lname");
People* second_people = new People(*my_people);
```

assuming that you have already implemented the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) as you should.

Now back to the question. For C++/Cli you also should implement copy constructor and assignment operator like

```
People(const People % other) { ... }
const People % operator = (const People % other) { ... ; return *this;}
```

And if we apply this to your question :

```
People^  my_people = gcnew People("name","lname");
People^ second_people = gcnew People(*my_people);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign `my_people` to `second_people` like this: `second_people = my_people`. This is because you are using references anyway.

Here is some complete example:

```
using namespace System;

ref class People {
public:
    String^ name;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    People^ myPeople = gcnew People();
    People^ secondPeople = myPeople;
    myPeople->name = gcnew String(L"My People");
    Console::WriteLine(secondPeople->name);
    return 0;
}
```

It will print `My People`.

Comment: But I think your code changes the content of secondPeople. I mean, now the name of the secondPeople is "My People". Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. You will need a copy constructor in your ref class then.